# Electron desktopCapturer window capture lag and high latency

Tags: javascript, electron, desktopcapturer

When I try to capture a window in Electron I get a very laggy (around 15fps) and high latency result, but when I capture the entire screen it works just fine.

Maybe it is because I'm running `getSource()` under `createWindow()`, but again screen capture works just fine.

I'm using basically the same code in
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/desktop-capturer

```
function createWindow() {

...

  function getSource() {
    desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ["window", "screen"] }).then(async (sources) => {
      for (const source of sources) {
        if (source.name.toLowerCase().includes("screen 1")) {
          // if (source.name === "Screen 1") {
          mainWindow.webContents.send("SET_SOURCE", source.id);
          return;
        }
        console.log(source.name);
      }
    });
  }
  getSource();
}
```

I already tried adding frame rate limitations:

```
...

      video: {
        mandatory: {
          chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
          chromeMediaSourceId: sourceId,
          minFrameRate: 30, // here
          maxFrameRate: 60,
          minWidth: 1280,
          maxWidth: 1280,
          minHeight: 720,
          maxHeight: 720,
        },

...
```